# How to pass an array as an argument from providers in PHPUnit?

Tags: php, phpunit

I have a test method that receives an array as an argument, and I want to feed the data from a data provider method?

how can that be achieved?

```
public function dataProvider(){
        return array(array(
                'id'=>1,
                'description'=>'',
        ));
}

/**
 * @dataProvider dataProvider
 */
public function testAddDocument($data){
// data here shall be an array provided by the data provider
// some test data here
}
```

What happens is that it passes the value of 'id' key ...etc

I want to pass the whole array

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Data provider methods must return an array containing one array for each set of arguments to pass to the test method. To pass an array, include it with the other arguments. Note that in your sample code you'll need another enclosing array.

Here's an example that returns two sets of data, each with two arguments (an array and a string).

```
public function dataProvider(): array
{
    return
        [// data sets
            [// data set 0
                [// first argument data set 0
                    'id'          => 1,
                    'description' => 'this',
                ],
                'foo',//second argument data set 0
            ],
            [//data set 1
                [//first argument data set 1
                    'id'          => 2,
                    'description' => 'that',
                ],
                'bar',//second argument data set 1       
            ],
        ];
}
```

**Important:** Data provider methods must be non-static. PHPUnit instantiates the test case to call each data provider method.

Comment: I'm testing your solution, but About the non-static the manual itself is making it static: http://www.phpunit.de/manual/3.2/en/writing-tests-for-phpunit.html

Comment: Your link is to the (very old) 3.2 version. It is shown as non-static in the [documentation for the current 3.6 release](http://www.phpunit.de/manual/3.6/en/writing-tests-for-phpunit.html).

Comment: Oh! thanks for notifying me about that, and thanks alot for your solution

Answer (score 0):

For clarity, I like to write the providers building variables that name what is what. Clean Coding rulez.

For this example, I'll start with a simple data provider that gets 2 phone numbers and 2 numbers. At the end I go with your particular example.

First of all, I always name the `$tests` variable, which makes it clear I'm going to return an "array of items representing a test":

```
public function successProvider() : array
{
    $tests = [
        [ '+11 111 11 11 111', '+11 111 11 11 111', 1, 2 ],
        [ '+11 111 11 11 111', '+55 555 55 55 555', 2, 3 ],
    ];

    return $tests;
}
```

If the test cases get more complex, I name them one by one assigning a key in the array:

```
public function successProvider() : array
{
    $tests = [
        'same phone' => [ '+11 111 11 11 111', '+11 111 11 11 111', 1, 2 ],
        'phone changed' => [ '+11 111 11 11 111', '+55 555 55 55 555', 2, 3 ],
    ];

    return $tests;
}
```

If each test case gets more complex I name each one in separated variables, like this:

```
public function successProvider() : array
{
    $testSamePhone = [
        '+11 111 11 11 111',
        '+11 111 11 11 111',
        1,
        2,
    ];

    $testPhoneChanged = [
        '+11 111 11 11 111',
        '+55 555 55 55 555',
        2,
        3,
    ];

    $tests = [
        $testSamePhone,
        $testPhoneChanged,
    ];

    return $tests;
}
```

To clarify what is each thing, some times I set a key inside each test. I usually make those keys similar to the variable names in the test receiving the parameters. Looks like this:

```
public function successProvider() : array
{
    $testSamePhone = [
        'possibleNumber' => '+11 111 11 11 111',
        'realNumber' => '+11 111 11 11 111',
        'numberOfLogCalls' => 1,
        'numberOfEvents' => 2,
    ];

    $testPhoneChanged = [
        'possibleNumber' => '+11 111 11 11 111',
        'realNumber' => '+55 555 55 55 555',
        'numberOfLogCalls' => 2,
        'numberOfEvents' => 3,
    ];

    $tests = [
        $testSamePhone,
        $testPhoneChanged,
    ];

    return $tests;
}
```

Now it becames super readable and without the need of "comments" (Clean Code rules advocates for the code speaking by itself).

Now, what if the input phone number instead of a number is an array of numbers? Say instead of "one `possibleNumber`" we have "a set of `possibleNumbers`":

```
public function successProvider() : array
{
    $testSamePhone = [
        'possibleNumbers' => [ '+11 111 11 11 111', '+3 333 333', '+999 999 9 9 9 9' ],
        'realNumber' => '+11 111 11 11 111',
        'numberOfLogCalls' => 1,
        'numberOfEvents' => 2,
    ];

    $testPhoneChanged = [
        'possibleNumbers' => [ '+11 111 11 11 111', '+3 333 333',  ],
        'realNumber' => '+55 555 55 55 555',
        'numberOfLogCalls' => 2,
        'numberOfEvents' => 3,
    ];

    $tests = [
        $testSamePhone,
        $testPhoneChanged,
    ];

    return $tests;
}
```

## In your case

I'd write the data provider like this:

```
public function dataProvider() : array
{
    $testDescriptiveNameOfTheTestCase = [
        'data' => [ 'id' => 1, 'description' => '' ],
    ];
    
    $tests = [
        $testDescriptiveNameOfTheTestCase,
    ];
    
    return $tests;
}
```

or, more compact:

```
public function dataProvider() : array
{
    $tests = [
        'Descriptive name of the Test Case' => [
            'data' => [ 'id' => 1, 'description' => '' ],
        ],
    ];

    return $tests;
}
```